# Sorting siblings in a hierarchy of objects

Tags: sorting, tree, rendering, hierarchical-data, scenegraph

I've implemented a scene tree to be used in a 2D game. The tree nodes contain transformations and drawable objects.

This is what the scene tree looks like:

```
                    Root
                     |
        --------------------------
        |                        |
      Layer1                   Layer2
        |                        |
-----------------            ---------
|       |       |            |       |
A       B       C            F       G
        |
    ---------
    |       |
    D       E
```

In order to draw the scene the tree is first traversed in depth-first order. During traversal the drawables are collected in a render queue. The render queue is then passed to a renderer to be processed.

As the drawables are collected in depth-first order, this is also the order in which they are drawn by the renderer. To change the drawing order I have to rearrange tree nodes. If, for example, I want node G to be drawn before node F, I have to swap them. I would like to change that so that the nodes don't have to be rearranged anymore. Instead the renderer should be able to sort the render queue by itself.

**The problem:**

Each group of sibling nodes (e.g. [A, B, C] or [F, G] or [D, E]) has to be sorted individually so that the hierarchy stays intact. If the tree nodes are sorted directly this is not a problem. However, if the tree is flattened to a render queue, things become complicated.

**My questions:**

How can I sort the render queue without disturbing the hierarchy of nodes?
Are there alternative solutions for this kind of problem?

**Additional info:**

The best resource I could find is the blog article [Order your graphics draw calls around](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=86). It explains how to sort a render queue using a 64-bit key that is assembled from multiple chunks of information. It doesn't deal with the problem I have, though.

You might ask why I don't content myself with sorting the tree nodes directly. There are two reasons: Firstly, I would like to keep concerns separated. Rearranging nodes in the scene tree so that the renderer draws them in the right order would not be conducive to this goal. Secondly, it would not be possible to exclude non-visible nodes/drawables from sorting (whereas the render queue only contains visible drawables).